# What are the main elements of Stoicism?

Tags: definitions, life, ancient-philosophy, stoicism, epicurus

My question is this:  What are the main elements of Stoicism?

As a secondary question, it would also be nice to know how Epicureanism compares to or contrasts with Stoicism.

Primary source material would be helpful.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/ and https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epicurus/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Annika Thanks Annika, that's more than I wanted to know about Stoicism.  (-: